# Multiple dictionaries/strings making it through if statements that shouldn't

Tags: python

The title is a bit vague but I can't think of a way to properly describe my issue in such a short space.

I have a Python (3.x) script that keeps track of reminders that users set for themselves.

The data of the reminders is saved in dictionary entries that are then stored in a tuple (because PyMySQL pulls the data from the database as a tuple).

When a reminder needs to be deleted, you need to create a new tuple without that dictionary because tuples are immutable. This means you use a for loop to go through the dictionaries and only import the ones that do not match the one that was deleted.

This is where my problem comes in. I'll put the snippet of code below.

```
global tReminders
tReminders2 = ()
for dic in tReminders:
    if user_name != dic.get("user_name") and reminder_text != dic.get("reminder_text") and group_name != dic.get("group_name") and set_time != dic.get("set_time") and reminder_time != dic.get("reminder_time"):
        print("ADDING: " + str(dic))
        tReminders2 += (dic,)
    else:
        print("SKIPPING: " + str(dic))
tReminders = tReminders2
```

For example, the initial tuple data is:

```
({'user_name': 'phil', 'reminder_text': 'test1', 'group_name': 'test', 'set_time': 1533074918, 'reminder_time': 1533074928}, {'user_name': 'phil', 'reminder_text': 'test2', 'group_name': 'test', 'set_time': 1533074920, 'reminder_time': 1533074930}, {'user_name': 'phil', 'reminder_text': 'test3', 'group_name': 'test', 'set_time': 1533074923, 'reminder_time': 1533074933})
```

As you can see, the for loop goes through the dictionaries in the outdated tuple and should be grabbing all the ones that do not match the deleted dictionary and storing them in the new tuple.

This is not the case however. For some reason that I can't see (could be a simple error that I'm just blind to), it is skipping over ALL the dictionaries in the old tuple and leaving the new one empty.

Any ideas?

Comment: You seem to be requiring mismatches in every field.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a **clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @Joooeey Is there something I'm missing? I included information on what it's doing, what is should do, and code to replicate it.

Comment: @user2357112 Yes, because tuples are immutable I need to grab all the mismatches from the old tuple.

Comment: You haven't assigned the values of the variables user_name, reminder_text etc. in the code you posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, you only grab a dictionary from the old tuple if *every value* in the dictionary is different from the deleted dictionary.

Based on your question it seems that you want to grab a dictionary from the old tuple if *any value* in the dictionary is different from the deleted dictionary (i.e. the only dictionary you want to exclude from the new tuple is the one that has been deleted).

Switch every `and` to `or` in your `if` statement and your code should behave as expected (assuming I'm right that you only want to exclude the dictionary that's been deleted).

Comment: THANK YOU! I knew it must have been something so simple I'd completely miss it.